# mvc and entity framework, display results of linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to return the results of a query that is written in linq to my view page for a MVC application.

I want to call my view, then pass the model, the model would have the results of my query.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult YourAction() {
  var results = GetResultsFromLinqQuery();
  return View(results);
}

public List<SomeObject> GetResultsFromLinqQuery() {
   var queryResults = // get these from your linq query
   return queryResults;
}
```

If you strongly type your view to expect results, then you can access them using `Model`.

**Edit:**

If your results is a List then in the view replace

`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"`

with

`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<SomeObject>>"`

**Edit 2:**

If all of this is not making much sense to you, I suggest you to take a look at [Nerd Dinner](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx) tutorial for ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: how can i add my result if i want it to be strongly typed?

Comment: what would be the return type of GetResultsFromLinqQuery(); return a list?

can you show me how you would declare GetResultsFromLinqQuery(); to return the poper list

Comment: I just want to know how i should declare GetResultsFromLinqQuery();

Comment: OK, hopefully that will give some help then, do accept posts as answers if they helped to solve your problem. Thanks